# Disable audio listener warnings? "There are no audio listeners...", "There are 2 audio listeners..."

Tags: unity

The scene I'm working in constantly spams the message `There are no audio listeners in the scene. Please ensure there is always one audio listener in the scene`. If I add a dummy camera with an Audio Listener, I then get `There are 2 audio listeners in the scene. Please ensure there is always exactly one audio listener in the scene`.

I know this happens because our camera is created programmatically, with an audio listener.  I also realize this will not affect the non-development build in any way.

Is it possible to disable these warnings completely?

Comment: Would you want to add the listener programmatically to the camera at creation? Or you just want to disable the error message?

Comment: The listener is added programmatically, thus the "There are 2 audio listeners" error when I add a static one.  I would like to disable the messages.

Comment: you said that the two listeners error comes when you add a listener to the dummy camera. I'm asking if you wanted to add it programmatically to the camera you are adding programmatically, and not have the dummy camera at all. But ok, you just want to disable the error. How will you have sound then? You want to use the dummy camera? That would create a lot of weird problems....

Comment: Remove listener from your camera and create prefab from camera then use it

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new to Unity and I'm just trying to clean up this scene.  Our character camera is created programmatically and you CAN hear sounds.  I'm only assuming that an Audio Listener is being programmatically attached, thus the "2 listeners" error when I add one statically.  Does that clear anything up?

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/927548/how-do-you-find-2-audio-listeners-in-scene.html

Comment: As expected, when I search for type "audiolistener" I don't find anything.  Which is why it normally says "There are no audio listeners".

Comment: I have reworded the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up enabling the Audio Listener on our login camera, then destroying it programmatically when the player camera spawns (this is what was causing the issue).

```
 staticCamera= GameObject.Find("StaticCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
 Destroy(staticCamera.GetComponent<AudioListener>());
```